# あるGistをStar込みでGitHubへ移行することはできますか？

Tags: github

Gistで管理しているものをGitHubに移行しようとしています。
GitHub側に新規リポジトリを作成してそこにブランチを移行するのは簡単ですが、
Gistに付与されたStarをGitHubへ移行する手段はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

残念ながら無理だと思います．無理であることの証明は困難ですが，いくつか間接的な根拠を与えることはできます．

まず gist から GitHub への移行は GitHub 公式の機能として特別のサポートはされておらず，やるとしたら単に純粋な Git の機能として新しいリモートリポジトリを登録するということになります．2つのリモートリポジトリ間の関係というのは Git それ自体の機能の上での関係に過ぎないので，star のように GitHub 固有のパラメータを共有する合理性がなさそうです．

また star はリポジトリの内容というよりも，そのリポジトリ自体に与えられているという性格が強いように思います．GitHub・gist それぞれのサービス内においてフォーク機能を用いればリポジトリを複製することは容易ですが，star 情報は引き継がれません．いわんやサービス間を跨ぐ場合をやです．

最後に GitHub 自身の広報ブログを検索してみても，それらしい記事は見当たりません．
https://github.blog/?s=gist+star

以上から，gist から GitHub に star 込みで移行する方法は存在しない蓋然性が高いと思われます．